# angularjs -- Playing around with angular-bootstrap-lightbox and it give me a type error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I've been working at this for about 5 hours and I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. The code was copied from http://compact.github.io/angular-bootstrap-lightbox/demo6/ I'm new to angular and stuck.

This is what I have in my controller:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('portfolio.photography',[
  'bootstrapLightbox',
  'ngRoute'
])
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/photography', {
        templateUrl: 'photography/photography.html',
        controller: 'PhotographyCtrl'
    });
}])
.controller('PhotographyCtrl',[
  '$scope', function($scope, Lightbox) {
    $scope.openLightboxModal = function (index) {
        Lightbox.openModal($scope.images, index);
    };
}])
```

This the error I get:

angular.js:14199 TypeError: Cannot read property 'openModal' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

You miss add the Ligthbox injection in the brackets

```
['$scope', 'Lightbox', function($scope, Lightbox){}]
```

**UPDATE**
 I make a plnkr with all dependencies needed to work based on your, i think you need to include ui-bootstrap dependency. check this out

[example](https://embed.plnkr.co/PPItOoaGFG1C9HQuDlvG/)

Comment: I've tried that too and my whole page goes blank and I get this error --- Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $uibModalProvider <- $uibModal <- Lightbox <- Lightbox

Comment: maybe has ui-bootstrap dependency.

Comment: your plnk not work for me.. it have alot of issue for dependcy files.. however, i make a plnkr the only think i dont have the jpg files. but it show the modal. Check it out.

Comment: I was able to get it to work but I also just get fail to load error once I click on it. Thanks so much for the help I really appreciate!

Comment: if you know pleas update with the right answer for other people who might have the same issue, glad to help.